# How to never mock a particular module with jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, automocking

In particular our codebase uses underscore in many places, and I never want to mock underscore. I know I can `jest.unmock('underscore');` in each test that interacts with underscore. Is there a way to unmock underscore globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to package.json.

```js
"jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "enzyme",
      "react",
      "react-addons-test-utils"
    ],
    "verbose": true
  }
```